# Looping through a file using a column

Tags: linux, bash, shell, files

I am trying to loop through a file named file.txt that contains a bunch of junk and one column (column #4) I am interested in. I want this loop to run from 0 to eof. For each value in column 4, I want to call another script.

Comment: Can you provide a copy of file.txt? So we understand what you are working with.

Comment: Do you want to call the same script once per line? Presumably with the value of column 4 as an argument to it? If so, please [edit] your question to say so.

Comment: Just in case @roaima was right, you can think something like `./myscript $( awk '{print $4} file.txt' )`

Answer (score 4):

To call a script for each value in colum #4, you can use something like this:

```
awk '{system("./your_script.sh " $4)}' inputfile
```

Comment: I'd suggest full path to the script instead of `./your_script.sh` as it refers to the script being present in the current directory, which may not be the case

Answer (score 2):

Yet another version how it could be done, this time with shell builtins only:

```
while read line ; do
    set $line
    echo $4
done <filename
```

Replace `echo` with your script.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that your columns are separated by whitespace.

```
for value in $(cat file.txt | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f4); do
  ./my_script.sh $value
done
```

Explanation:

- `tr -s ' '` squelches consecutive spaces so that columns are separated by single space
- `cut -d ' ' -f4` uses single space as delimiter to choose 4th column

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised no one has mentioned `xargs`, because that's precisely the purpose of `xargs` to provide values outputed by previous command to something else.  We can combine that property with `awk`'s  ability to print columns. Bellow is sample demo. You can replace `printf "Hello %s\n"` part with your script

```
xieerqi@eagle:~$ df > testFile.txt
xieerqi@eagle:~$ awk '{print $4}' testFile.txt | xargs -I {} printf "Hello %s\n" {}
Hello Available
Hello 26269816
Hello 4
Hello 2914488
Hello 584064
Hello 5120
Hello 2827976
Hello 102324
```

Answer (score -2):

```
sed 1d $outfile1 | while read "column on file" do

done
```