# looping through a file of two columns

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, command-line

My question is basically a follow up question on [this topic](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/242625/looping-through-a-file-using-a-column).
I have a file like this:

```
1000 | line1
100  | line2
10   | line3
```

I want to do something on $2 if $1 is greater than 20. I wrote something to mimic the [2nd answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/242638/258220) but it doesn't work:

```
for a, b in $(cat file.text|cut -d"|" -f 1,2);
do
if ($1>20) echo $2
done;
```

How can I achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at [How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) -- there are example there about reading multiple fields from each line into variables.

Comment: You'll also want to read about Conditional blocks at http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -F'|' '$1 > 20 { system("/path/to/another/script.sh "$2 }' < file.text
```

This tells awk to split the input up into fields based on the pipe symbol. Any first field whose value is greater than 20 triggers the system call to ... anything you want. Keep in mind that the argument (here $2, but it could be $0 or any other calculation you do in awk) is passed to the script via a shell call, so if those values can contain shell-special characters, carefully quote it. I'll refer to [one of Stéphane's answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/113799/117549) for an example of how to do that:

```
awk 'function escape(s) {
       gsub(/'\''/,"&\\\\&&",s)
       return "'\''" s "'\''"
     }
     { system("/path/to/another/script.sh" escape($2)) }'
```

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I am looking for. I used a work-around like this:`awk -F"|" '{if ($1>20) print "script.sh " $2}' |bash`. But your solution is better! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

With `awk`:

```
$ for param in $(awk '$1 > 20 { print $3 }' inputfile); do ./process.sh "$param"; done
```

Comment: oh sorry I didn't say it clearly in the question - I am doing something other than just `echo`. I actually need to do `./process.sh $2`. Right now my solution is use awk to generate a new script that repeats `./process.sh $2` many times.

Comment: I have modified my answer accordingly.  It effectively does what you describe, but without actually writing a script.

Comment: Careful if the second column contains spaces...

Comment: The second column as described is `|`.

Comment: Thanks @DopeGhoti! This is a great answer as well. Too bad system doesn't allow me accept two answers.

Comment: @DopeGhoti Sorry, I meant the 3rd column, the data after the pipe.

Answer (score 2):

You wouldn't really want to parse data in the shell itself, but to use a tool like `awk` to do it for you.

```
awk -F '[[:blank:]|]+' '$1 > 20 { print $2 }' file
```

This instructs `awk` to treat each line of the file as a set of fields delimited by any number of pipe-symbols or blanks (spaces or tabs). When the first field is greater than 20, the second field is printed.

Related:

- [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)

---

If the second column contain blanks, then you may want to use `[[:blank:]]*[|][[:blank:]]*` as the delimiter:

```
awk -F '[[:blank:]]*[|][[:blank:]]*' '$1 > 20 { print $2 }' file
```

The `[|]` matches a literal pipe symbol, and may be replaced by `\\|` (if you enjoy backslashes).

---

The following executes a script with each instance of the second column whose first column is greater than 20 as the command line argument:

```
awk -F '[[:blank:]]*[|][[:blank:]]*' '$1 > 20 { print $2 }' file |
xargs -I XX ./script.sh XX
```

With something like `-P 4` as an option to `xargs`, you can run multiple parallel instances of your script at once (four with `-P 4`).

Answer (score 0):

You can try with gnu sed too

```
sed -E 's/([0-9]*) \| (.*)/[ \1 -gt 20 ] \&\& echo do something with \2/e' infile
```